# Replacing fixed json variable with a json value returned from a php file

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js

I have a JavaScript code where the dataset is hard-coded in a variable, like this -

```
var dataset = [
              {category: "Dept 1", measure: 0.30},
              {category: "Dept 2", measure: 0.25},
              {category: "Dept 4", measure: 0.15},
              {category: "Dept 3", measure: 0.05},
              {category: "Dept 5", measure: 0.18},
              {category: "Dept 6", measure: 0.04},
              {category: "Dept 7", measure: 0.03}
              ]
              ;
```

Now I want to use the json data which is getting returned from a php file (fetching through mysql query).

Whats the effective way to do this. does getJSON works well in this case?

Note-  I am working on a pie chart in d3.js and this dataset requirement is for that chart.

**EDIT -** 
This is how the code looks after suggested changes-

```js
function dsPieChart(){


 var    width = 400,
     height = 400,
     outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
     innerRadius = outerRadius * .999,   
     // for animation
     innerRadiusFinal = outerRadius * .5,
     innerRadiusFinal3 = outerRadius* .45,
     color = d3.scale.category20()    //builtin range of colors
     ;
 

 d3.json("data/mixchart.php", function(error, dataset) { 

    if (error) return console.warn(error);
    else 
    {
 var vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
      .append("svg:svg")              //create the SVG element inside the <body>
      .data([dataset])                   //associate our data with the document
          .attr("width", width)           //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
          .attr("height", height)
        .append("svg:g")                //make a group to hold our pie chart
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")    //move the center of the pie chart from 0, 0 to radius, radius
    ;
    
   var arc = d3.svg.arc()              //this will create <path> elements for us using arc data
         .outerRadius(outerRadius).innerRadius(innerRadius);
   
   // for animation
   var arcFinal = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal).outerRadius(outerRadius);
 var arcFinal3 = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal3).outerRadius(outerRadius);

   var pie = d3.layout.pie()           //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
        .value(function(d) { return d.measure; });    //we must tell it out to access the value of each element in our data array

   var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")     //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
        .data(pie)                          //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties) 
        .enter()                            //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
            .append("svg:g")                //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
               .attr("class", "slice")    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)
               .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout)
        .on("click", up)
        ;
        
        arcs.append("svg:path")
               .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
               .attr("d", arc)     //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
     .append("svg:title") //mouseover title showing the figures
       .text(function(d) { return d.data.category + ": " + formatAsPercentage(d.data.measure); });   

        d3.selectAll("g.slice").selectAll("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
       .delay(10)
       .attr("d", arcFinal )
       ;
 
   // Add a label to the larger arcs, translated to the arc centroid and rotated.
   // source: http://bl.ocks.org/1305337#index.html
   arcs.filter(function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; })
     .append("svg:text")
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arcFinal.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")"; })
       //.text(function(d) { return formatAsPercentage(d.value); })
       .text(function(d) { return d.data.category; })
       ;
    
    // Computes the label angle of an arc, converting from radians to degrees.
  function angle(d) {
      var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
      return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
  }
      
  
  // Pie chart title   
  vis.append("svg:text")
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text("Revenue Share 2012")
       .attr("class","title")
       ;      
    }
    });

  
 function mouseover() {
   d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
           //.attr("stroke","red")
           //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
           .attr("d", arcFinal3)
           ;
 }
 
 function mouseout() {
   d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
           //.attr("stroke","blue")
           //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
           .attr("d", arcFinal)
           ;
 }
 
 function up(d, i) {
 
    /* update bar chart when user selects piece of the pie chart */
    //updateBarChart(dataset[i].category);
    updateBarChart(d.data.category, color(i));
    updateLineChart(d.data.category, color(i));
    
 }
}


dsPieChart();
```

Edit 2 -

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
    
/*
################ FORMATS ##################
-------------------------------------------
*/


var  formatAsPercentage = d3.format("%"),
  formatAsPercentage1Dec = d3.format(".1%"),
  formatAsInteger = d3.format(","),
  fsec = d3.time.format("%S s"),
  fmin = d3.time.format("%M m"),
  fhou = d3.time.format("%H h"),
  fwee = d3.time.format("%a"),
  fdat = d3.time.format("%d d"),
  fmon = d3.time.format("%b")
  ;


 
 
var     width = 400,
     height = 400,
     outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
     innerRadius = outerRadius * .999,   
     // for animation
     innerRadiusFinal = outerRadius * .5,
     innerRadiusFinal3 = outerRadius* .45,
     color = d3.scale.category20()    //builtin range of colors
     ;


d3.json("data/mixchart.php", function(error,data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.category =d.category;
    d.measure = d.measure;
  });

  //if (err) return console.warn(err);
    
 var vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
      .append("svg:svg")              //create the SVG element inside the <body>
      .data(data)                   //associate our data with the document
          .attr("width", width)           //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
          .attr("height", height)
        .append("svg:g")                //make a group to hold our pie chart
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")    //move the center of the pie chart from 0, 0 to radius, radius
    ;
   
   var arc = d3.svg.arc()              //this will create <path> elements for us using arc data
         .outerRadius(outerRadius).innerRadius(innerRadius);
   
   // for animation
   var arcFinal = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal).outerRadius(outerRadius);
   var arcFinal3 = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal3).outerRadius(outerRadius);

   var pie = d3.layout.pie()           //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
        .value(function(d) { return d.measure; });    //we must tell it out to access the value of each element in our data array

   var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")     //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
        .data(pie)                          //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties) 
        .enter()                            //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
            .append("svg:g")                //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
               .attr("class", "slice")    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)
               .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout)
        .on("click", up)
        ;
        
        arcs.append("svg:path")
               .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
               .attr("d", arc)     //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
     .append("svg:title") //mouseover title showing the figures
       .text(function(d) { return d.data.category + ": " + formatAsPercentage(d.data.measure); });   

        d3.selectAll("g.slice").selectAll("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
       .delay(10)
       .attr("d", arcFinal )
       ;
 
   // Add a label to the larger arcs, translated to the arc centroid and rotated.
   // source: http://bl.ocks.org/1305337#index.html
   arcs.filter(function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; })
     .append("svg:text")
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arcFinal.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")"; })
       //.text(function(d) { return formatAsPercentage(d.value); })
       .text(function(d) { return d.data.category; })
       ;
     
    // Computes the label angle of an arc, converting from radians to degrees.
  function angle(d) {
      var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
      return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
  }
      
   
        
  // Pie chart title   
  vis.append("svg:text")
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text("Revenue Share 2012")
       .attr("class","title")
       ;      
   
     
 function mouseover() {
   d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
           //.attr("stroke","red")
           //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
           .attr("d", arcFinal3)
           ;
 }
 
 function mouseout() {
   d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
           //.attr("stroke","blue")
           //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
           .attr("d", arcFinal)
           ;
 }
 
 function up(d, i) {
 
    /* update bar chart when user selects piece of the pie chart */
    //updateBarChart(dataset[i].category);
    updateBarChart(d.data.category, color(i));
    updateLineChart(d.data.category, color(i));
    
 }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataset = [];
$.getJSON("your_php_file", function(result){
        dataset = result;
});
```

this will work but keep in mind that your php file is returning only json... rest you can play with the options.

Comment: I replaced the fixed dataset with above code but its still not working. what am i missing?

Comment: var dataset = [];
 $.getJSON("data/mixchart.php", function(result){
    dataset = result;
 });

Comment: Check the following:

Comment: you missed something

Comment: Check the following:
1. Is your php page url working?
2. Is it returning JSON?
3. If the php page is accessible and returning JSON, then probably you are getting data in the `dataset` variable. But since `getJSON` is asynchronous call, the value in the `dataset` variable will be set after the rest statements are executed in the `dsPieChart()` function. So move all the statements following the variable `dataset` in getJSON function.

Comment: Yes, the json data is coming from php and its just json. what you are saying is correct about getJSON but is their any other way than using json. actually I am unable to restructure the code for getJSON call ..

Comment: var dataset = [];
$.getJSON("your_php_file", function(result){
        dataset = result;
        dsPieChart();  // call the function here instead of doing outside
});

Comment: If you want to send any data other than JSON, simply use AJAX call instead of getJSON.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways of fetching JSON, but as you're already working with d3, `d3.json` would be a good way to go.

E.g.

```
d3.json('your/json.json', function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  doSomethingWithJson(json)
});
```

Also see [the d3 API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json)